# Passing python list in hive query as parameters

Tags: hive

```
   from tkinter import *
    import pyodbc
    with pyodbc.connect("DSN=ffff", autocommit=True) as conn:
          df2 = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM holdingsummarysaaas", conn)
          list46 = []
          for md in df2['clientcode']:
               list46.append(md)
          print(list46)
          result = []
          for i in list46:
              if i not in result:
              result.append(i)
          print(result)
          #list_no_nan = [x for x in result if pd.notnull(x)]
          #print(list_no_nan)
          #select name from studens where id in (%s)" % ",".join(map(str,mylist)
          #def fun():
          num1 = Entry(root)
          blank = Entry(root)
          Ans = (num1.get())
          blank.insert(0, Ans)
          if Ans in result:
              df2 = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM holdingsummary where ' + ' or '.join(('clientcode = ' 
              + str(n) for n in result)),conn)
              #df2 = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM holdingsummary  where clientcode = '" + Ans + "'", 
              conn)
              print(df2)
```

I am taking unique clientcodes from database and I want user input which is in fun
          function should access the results list(unique clientcode )check each clientcode from list 
          and check whether entered clientcode if same in result list then open that clientcode.
         for eg:

```
Ans=='100014'  
         #df2 = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM holdingsummarysaaas  where clientcode = '100014', conn)
```